# Web Share API в Microsoft EDGE

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываю сайт в Microsoft EDGE в эмуляции мобильного устройства через DevTools, на сайте стоит кнопка "Поделиться", которая подгружается если navigator.share == true, в EDGE кнопка подгружается, но при клике на ней в консоле появляется ошибка - Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Share failed. Смотрел тут - https://world-weather.ru/pogoda/russia/moscow/

Если все тоже самое проделывать в Chrome, то в нем navigator.share == false, т.е. все работает корректно и кнопка не подгружается, потому что она и не нужна по факту на десктопе.

Это фича EDGE или очередной баг?